# rle command counting changes in vector

Tags: r

```
n   <- length(rle(sign(z)))
```

z contains 1 and -1. n should indicate the number of how many times the sign of z changes.

The code above does not lead to the desired outcome. If I expand the command to

```
length(rle(sign(z))[[1]])
```

it works. I don't understand the underlying mechanism of how [[1]] solves the problem?

Comment: If `z` only contains -1 and 1 then the call to `sign` is redundant.

Comment: Then you should read `help(rle)`, specifically the *Value* section

Comment: Another solution for your problem: `sum(diff(z) != 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rle` returns a list consisting of two components: `lengths`, and `values`. As such, its own `length` is always 2. By contrast, you want to know the length of either of those components (they obviously have the same length). So either `length(rle(…)[[1]])` or `length(rle(…)[[2]])` would work. Better to use the names instead of an index though, e.g.

```
length(rle(z)$lengths)
```

However, this won’t be the number of times the sign changes; rather, it will be the number of times the changes plus 1.